# update database table from scrapy using Request Meta

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

This is my first question here at stackoverflow
I'm playing around with Scrapy and I'm stuck where I want to update the database link to scanned = 1 once the link have been taken from Scrapy.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import scrapy.http
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from Testing.items import Testing100Item
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Response
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.responsetypes import Response
import re
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb.cursors import SSCursor
import MySQLdb.cursors

##This is the connector to Database to Read New Domains
def getdomainsfromdb():
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="root",
            db="Testing",
            cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = """
                SELECT domain_id, url, id_sitemap_links
                from Sitemap_links
                where scanned = 0;"""
        cursor.execute(query)
        return cursor.fetchall()
    except Exception, e:
        print e

##This will update the scanned to 1
def scanned(id_sitemap_links):
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="root",
            db="Testing",
            cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = """
            UPDATE Sitemap_links
            set scanned = 1
            where id_sitemap_links = '%s' """
        cursor.execute(query, (int(id_sitemap_links),))
    except Exception, e:
        print e

class Testing100Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "testing100"
    #allowed_domains = []
    #start_urls = ()

    def start_requests(self):
        for domain_id, url, id_sitemap_links in getdomainsfromdb():
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'id_sitemap_links': id_sitemap_links})

    def parse(self, response):

        # domain_id = response.meta['domain_id']
        id_sitemap_links = response.meta['id_sitemap_links']
        scanned(id_sitemap_links)
        print id_sitemap_links



        # def parse(self, response):
        #     domain_id = Request(0)
        #     item = Testing100Item()
        #     #items = []
```

At this time I can read domain from getdomainsfromdb() function, but I can not update the id of the domain that scrapy is working on.. 
I am able to print the id_sitemap_links but the SQL is not updating..

What am I missing here ? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to fix:

- remove the `enter code here` from the query (it is probably a posting error though)
- remove the quotes around the placeholder
- add `conn.commit()`

Fixed version:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    db="Testing",
    cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """
    UPDATE Sitemap_links
    set scanned = 1
    where id_sitemap_links = %s """
cursor.execute(query, (int(id_sitemap_links), ))
conn.commit()
```

Note that it is generally recommended to place the database-specific functionality into the pipelines and not into the spiders directly.

Comment: you saved my life :) 
I've been struggling with this for about 2 hours!